# How to make an SMB share seeming a regular directory?

Tags: macos, filesystems, smb, acdsee

I have an application ([ACDSee](https://www.acdsee.com/en/products/photo-studio-mac/)) that does not want to work with network shares in certain cases. Namely, it checks if the directory is a network share and refuses to add it into indexing list. Is there a way to trick the application so that id does not recognize that the directory is mapped to the network share? I tried creating a sym link to `/Volumes/MyShare` in my home directory, but the sly app detects it anyway. Any other ideas?

Comment: https://forum.acdsee.com/forum/main-category/acdsee-ultimate/49562-is-it-possible-how-to-to-use-network-storage-for-database-to-work-from-two-pc